# Datacontract in wcf

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

How to initialize class in WCF?

Suppose I just want to make a sum of two member in a class.

I have coded in iService like:

```
[DataContract]
class Sample
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public int q { get; set; }
}

[OperationContract]
public int Sum(Sample obj);
```

And in service:

```
public int Sum(Sample obj)
{
}
```

What added coding require to make that run, as I am confuse with the class declaration in both the pages?

Comment: you need to put DataMemberAttribute on your properties

Comment: sorry i missed that out. but in service page it shows the absence of sample object(that is obvious as i dnt have class their) but do we need to add class declaration again on service page? or some other way?>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, it would be set up like below.  You should clearly separate the service from the data contracts.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISampleService
{
        [OperationContract]
        int sum(SampleData obj);
}

public class SampleService : ISampleService
{
        public int sum(SampleData obj)
        {
           // logic here
        }
}

[DataContract]
public class SampleData
{
       [DataMember]
       public int i { get; set; }

       [DataMember]
       public int q { get; set; }
}
```